# Query to find GPA from score (negative GPA)

Tags: mysql

I have made project on JSP to calculate GPA (Grade Point Average) from score via MySQL database. Here's my formula:

```
sb=con.prepareStatement("select round((((score)/20)-1),1) from student");

<td>GPA</td>
<td><%= diss1.getDouble(1)%></td>
```

The problem is with above formula, if score is 100 it gives 4 GPA, and if score is 40 then it gives me 0 GPA. But for scores below 40 it gives me negative GPA. So I want query or any solution that gives me 0 value for all score < 40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use the `GREATEST` value between your computed value and zero:

```
SELECT GREATEST( ROUND((((score)/20)-1),1), 0 ) FROM student
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the inline IF statement:

```
SELECT IF(round((((score)/20)-1),1)<0,0,round((((score)/20)-1),1)) from student
```